# OpenAM giving "Error processing AuthnRequest. Unable to generate NameID value." error

Tags: security, saml, saml-2.0, openam, idp

I am using OpenAM as an in-house IDP service. The flow I am using is IDP initiated where-in I am using the below link:

`http://127.0.0.1:8080/openam/idpssoinit?metaAlias=%2Fidp&spEntityID=https%3A%2F%2Fmcrmpssso.maxlifeinsurance.com%2Fybl%2Fsps%2Fsamlybl%2Fsaml20`

The SP metadata.xml is as below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" validUntil="2020-06-06T05:29:49Z" cacheDuration="PT604800S" entityID="https://mcrmpssso.maxlifeinsurance.com/ybl/sps/samlybl/saml20">
  <md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="false" WantAssertionsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <!--md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
    </md:KeyDescriptor-->
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://mcrmpssso.maxlifeinsurance.com/ybl/sps/samlybl/saml20/login" index="1"/>
    <!--md:Organization>
        <md:OrganizationName xml:lang="en">MLIC</md:OrganizationName>
        <md:OrganizationDisplayName xml:lang="en">MLIC</md:OrganizationDisplayName>
        <md:OrganizationURL xml:lang="en"/>
    </md:Organization-->
  </md:SPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

IDP configured NameID format and value:
[image]

SP configured NameID format:
[image]

OpenAM's stack-trace:

```
libSAML2:04/05/2020 08:05:57:847 PM UTC: Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-5,5,main]: TransactionId[bf5ec287-6206-4f48-bba0-f968efd3146f-32206]
ERROR: Error processing request
com.sun.identity.saml2.common.SAML2Exception: Unable to generate NameID value.
    at com.sun.identity.saml2.plugins.DefaultIDPAccountMapper.getNameID(DefaultIDPAccountMapper.java:114)
    at com.sun.identity.saml2.profile.IDPSSOUtil.getSubject(IDPSSOUtil.java:1618)
    at com.sun.identity.saml2.profile.IDPSSOUtil.getAssertion(IDPSSOUtil.java:1009)
    ...
```

I am stuck at this issue since several hours. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if on the configured user data store has an user subject identity attribute 'uid' configured (see NameID Value Map screenshot) and you need to ensure a value is set for the user performing the IdP-initated SSO flow. For testing purpose, you may explicitly specify the NameID format to be used by adding request parameter `NameIDFormat=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified`

Comment: Tried this `http://idp.mintpro.in:8080/openam/idpssoinit?metaAlias=%2Fidp&spEntityID=https%3A%2F%2Fmcrmpssso.maxlifeinsurance.com%2Fybl%2Fsps%2Fsamlybl%2Fsaml20&NameIDFormat=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified` but didn't work.

Comment: FYI I am using the embedded repository in OpenAM

Comment: OpenAM does not store really store identity information, it only consumes identity information from configured user data stores. No matter which user data store is being used (not even when the 'embedded' is used ... it's just an OpenDJ being started when OpenAM web app is initialised)

Comment: The 'Federation' and 'IdRepo' debug logs (level set to 'message') will show why the value can not be determined.

Comment: I enabled the debug log and found this "AccountUtils.getAccountFederation : user does not have any account federations." followed by the stack-trace i mentioned in the question. Doesn't seem like an error. Should I use account repositories like LDAP or AD just to try if it works?